# How can I create a percentage table in R based on existing data?

Tags: r

I would like to know how i can create a new table of percentages based on data from an existing dataframe.

This is a a sample of the data I have been working with:

```
Sample All 1  2  3  4
1 E1   250 29 27 11 18
2 E2   210 36 24 28 21
3 E3   130 29 10 12 23
4 E4   140 33 24 22 14
5 E5   220 27 16 19 18
```

This is the dput of my code sample:

```
dd <- data.frame(
  Sample = c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5"), 
  `All` = c(250, 210, 130, 140, 220), 
  `1` = c(29, 36, 29, 33, 27), 
  `2` = c(27, 24, 10, 24, 16), 
  `3` = c(11, 28, 12, 22, 19), 
  `4` = c(18, 21, 27, 14, 18),
  check.names=FALSE
)
```

I am trying to calculate the percentages for all the values from column 3:5 against the value in column 2.

This is what my desired output looks like:

```
  Sample    All  1    2    3     4 
        1 E1   250 11.6 10.8 4.4   7.2
        2 E2   210 17.1 11.4 13.3  10
        3 E3   130 22.3 7.6  9.2   17.69
```

I have tried using prop.table however this doesn't give me my desired output

Comment: You hardly need `prop.table` to divide a number by another! You want to "calculate the percentages for all the values from column 3:5 against the value in column 2.". I am not sure you realise that it is just a long winded way of saying you want to divide columns 3:5 by column 2 (and multiply by 100 if you feel like it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the data frame yourself with just extracting columns and doing the division yourself. For example

```
data.frame(dd[,1:2], dd[,-(1:2)]/dd[,2] * 100, check.names=FALSE)
#   Sample All        1         2         3         4
# 1     E1 250 11.60000 10.800000  4.400000  7.200000
# 2     E2 210 17.14286 11.428571 13.333333 10.000000
# 3     E3 130 22.30769  7.692308  9.230769 20.769231
# 4     E4 140 23.57143 17.142857 15.714286 10.000000
# 5     E5 220 12.27273  7.272727  8.636364  8.181818
```

Here we take the first two columns, then we take all the other columns divided by the second column times 100.

Comment: Did you adapt the indices for your larger data frame?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mutate_at` in dplyr to select the columns you want to change, and provide an anonymous function (formula to be converted to function) of `~ 100*./All`.

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
  mutate_at(as.character(1:4), ~ 100*./All) 

#   Sample All        1         2         3         4
# 1     E1 250 11.60000 10.800000  4.400000  7.200000
# 2     E2 210 17.14286 11.428571 13.333333 10.000000
# 3     E3 130 22.30769  7.692308  9.230769 20.769231
# 4     E4 140 23.57143 17.142857 15.714286 10.000000
# 5     E5 220 12.27273  7.272727  8.636364  8.181818
```